# If you create a DomainService, exposing an entity, can you access aggregate entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services, odata

Say you create an RIA DomainService and you include a `Person` (shown below) entity in it, can you access aggregate entities on that object?

For instance, if I have entities like so (keep in mind that this is a naive representation, they are modeled via the EF4 designer):

```
public class Person
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    public string Trunk { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

If I include `Person` when creating the PeopleDomainService, can the client access the `PhoneNumber` on it (and modify it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can bring in related entities.

In the PeopleDomainService.metadata.cs file, look for the PersonMetadata class.  On the PhoneNumbers property, add the "Include" attribute:

```
[Include]:
public EntityCollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
```

In the PeopleDomainService.cs, look for the GetPersons function and modify it to include the PhoneNumbers:

```
public IQueryable<Person> GetPersons()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.Persons.Include("PhoneNumbers");
}
```

You can find more details on MSDN > [Walkthrough: Taking a Tour of RIA Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713719%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) > Displaying Related Data

Comment: +1. Thanks for the tip. For future readers, I also had to add the [Association(name, thisKey, otherKey)] attribute to the collection as well as the `Include` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can decorate the PhoneNumber attribute of the Person object with the [Include] attribute. Remember also to include an include statement in your LINQ query when you get a Person object.